# Regex capture group with back references

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

So I am trying to parse some text file with fairly repetitive patterns, and regex will just do the job just fine. But stumbled upon this scenario which looks like so:

```
2 people:
Juan
Gabriella
```

I wanted to group `Juan` and `Gabriella` so that the result of my Regexp looks like so:

Match 0: 2 people
   Group 1: Juan
   Group 2: Gabriella

I tried:

`/^\d+\speople.*:$\n(.*)$\n/gm`

And the result is:

```
Match 0: 2 people
Group 1: Juan
```

I think we can use back references, but unsure how it can be used in this scenario.

Regexr: https://regexr.com/3k86r

**Update:**

As the comments states, that it is unlikely to do it that way, so how about having `Juan` and `Gabriella` in the same group, and just split them afterward.

So the regex will now look for 3 consecutive line breaks to group the items `Juan\nGabriella` and `Foo\nBar\Bazz`

2 people:
Juan
Gabriella

3 people:
Foo
Bar
Bazz

Tried:

```
\d+\speople+:$([\s\S]*(?=\n{3,}))
```

https://regexr.com/3k888

Comment: In almost all regex dialects, including js, number of groups == number of parenthesis. So that's not possible, consider alternatives (`exec`, `match` with `/g`)

Comment: What's the javascript tag for? can you use the language?

Comment: @georg Except those which support `\G`.

Comment: i'll edit the question, so it may be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the regex will now look for 3 consecutive line breaks to group the items `Juan\nGabriella` and `Foo\nBar\Bazz`

You may use

```
/(?:^|\n)\d+\s*people:([\s\S]*?)(?=\n{3}|$)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dVSBom/1)

**Details**

- `(?:^|\n)` - start of string or LF
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `people:` - a literal substring
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars as few as possible before the first...
- `(?=\n{3}|$)` - 3 consecutive LF symbols or end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /(?:^|\n)\d+\s*people:([\s\S]*?)(?=\n{3}|$)/g;
var str = "2 people:\nJuan\nGabriella\n\n\n3 people:\nFoo\nBar\nBazz";
let m, res=[];
while (m=rx.exec(str)) {
  console.log(m[1].trim().split("\n"));
}
```